# Inject/merge medialibrary items into belongtomany relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have json like this:

```
"member_skills": [
    {
        "id": 69,
        "skill_type_id": 6,
        "title": "Piano",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "pivot": {
            "member_id": 4,
            "skill_id": 69,
            "description": "description",
            "other_skill": null
        }
    }
],
```

The relation is this:

```
public function memberSkills(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Skills::class, MemberSkill::class, null, 'skill_id')->withPivot("description", "other_skill", "name");
}
```

I have media library and I want to inject those media library items in subset of any skills.

Every skill has medias.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have properly set the `Skill` model to interact with `Media`.

You can't simply use `with('media')` in your `BelongsToMany` relationship definition. Instead, you can manually append media to your skills when you're fetching them like,

```
$member = Member::with('memberSkills')->find($memberId);

$member->memberSkills->each(function ($skill) {
    $skill->media = $skill->getMedia('media_collection');
});
```

And then you can return the skills for example is Json Response,

```
return response()->json($member->memberSkills);
```